# Where to begin when developing a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I am a beginner at web development and wanted to know where to begin when developing a web application. More specifically I am using RoR and wanted to know is there a particular stack developers start with for instance would it be better to start developing models or views? Or do I have the wrong approach all together.

Answer (score 1):

This will guide you through installation and 'hello world' in rails.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

And I highly recommend this book, if you are serious about rails. Finish it completely. It would give you insights which might take months to comprehend if you are searching only in web.

Book link: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0):

Rails sort of has two "default" stacks, as this blog post helpfully explains:

http://words.steveklabnik.com/rails-has-two-default-stacks

You'll see that mr. Klabnik also has some thoughts about the difficulty this creates for new developers. I'd recommend not worrying too much about all the different tools that are available to you at first. Wait until you have a problem or are experiencing some pain and then find a tool to solve that problem. Before that, just jump in and learn as you go. Or at least, that's how I'd approach it, but people learn differently!